# Are there any rules for modern weapons/armor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, armor, modern

As I looked over the Pathfinder rules - especially the weapons and armor stats from Paizo and different 3rd-party producers - I noticed that I saw stats for either scifi or fantasy items, but I did not find any stats for modern equipment (for example, an M16 or a bulletproof vest).

Do any Paizo or 3rd-party products provide rules for modern gear? (This includes burst-fire/auto-fire rules as well.)

Comment: As I'm not aware of the question being too specific or generic or a book buy question I would be interested what the reason behind the closing votes are? (so that I can adapt the question to better fit if I misunderstood some of the question rules)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about modern armor, but modern weaponry definitely exists along with the rules for it:

[Modern Firearms](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/firearms/modern-firearms/)

The page includes things such as mustard gas, automatic weapons, and artillery.

Comment: The "Modern" Firearms there have existed since before WW1 (1915). The M16 OP references was developed in 1964.

Comment: @Ifusaso The answer doesn't fully find that what I needed, but it goes into the right direction. Could easily be that it is the only possible answer :/

Comment: This is also true.

Comment: The rules also make it easier to homebrew more modern weapons.

Comment: ["since before WWI (**1915**)"](https://media.giphy.com/media/l3q2K5jinAlChoCLS/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Wizards of the Coast published d20 Modern back in the 3.5 edition d20 days. It was released under the Open Game License, so you can find it free and legally online in several places by searching for "d20 modern SRD".

Comment: While Pathfinder is supposedly retrocompatible with anything 3.5e (and possibly with d20 modern and other d20 products), those firearms are not part of Pathfinder proper.